# images not showing up in rask task with action mailer on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, rake-task

So I created a welcome email for my users. I want this email to be sent at a specific time so I nest it into a rake task and add it to my heroku scheduler.

The thing is, the email template has images.

When I open the console and type `UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_now`, everything work fine. Images do show up when I receive the email.

However, when I run `rake send_welcome_email`, the email get sent but none of the images show up inside.

Here is my user_mailer.rb:

```
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome !')
  end
```

my scheduler.rake:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on. It aims to send the second of the four welcome emails to new users"
task :send_welcome_email => :environment do
  users = User.find_by(email: "useremail@email.com")
  puts 'Sending welcome email...'
    UserMailer.welcome_email(users).deliver_now
  puts '...Done !'
end
```

and my image_tags in my welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<%= image_tag "myimage.svg" %>
<%= image_tag "email_images/myotherimage.jpg" %>
```

Notice that I have already tried to change the relative path like so:

- /myimage.svg
- /images/myimage.svg
- /assets/images/myimage.svg
- images/myimage.svg
- assets/images/myimage.svg

where could the problem come from ?

Comment: What are you seeing in the `src` attribute of the image when it doesn't show up? Guessing it looks something like `/myimage.svg`, and is missing the domain, correct?

Comment: yeah depending on the relative path I try to use, I get `http://localhost:3000/myimage.svg`. But even I manage to get `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/myimage.svg` which is the right path I guess, images still don't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is explicitly state which images you want in the mailer (UserMailer), like

```
attachments.inline['myimage.svg'] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s + '/app/assets/images/myimage.svg'}")
```

From there, you can call it in the mailer template with

```
<%= image_tag attachments.inline["myimage.svg"].url %>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much @Ted ! Actually I saw this solution in the docs and I thought I could find another way to get my images with a more DRY solution (to follow the Rails philosophy) But It seems to be the only and best working solution.